# Toolbar Implementation for redcarpet (Markdown interpreter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wysiwyg, markdown

I am looking to use the Redcarpet gem (https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) in an app of mine.

Is there some kind of toolbar add in that i can use to give users a toolbar with "stack-like" options (bold, italics, etc, etc) on textareas?

Answer (score 1):

Redcarpet is just Markdown. There are a few web-based Markdown editors out there, but my favorite is [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) since it's nice and light-weight. It's a jQuery-based editor for all kinds of markup/down/html/etc.